# Exception with WCF in MONO using Duplex Communication

Tags: wcf, mono, nettcpbinding, duplex

When I try to run my Project (with duplex Net TCP Connection), wich is working with NET 4.0 verry well, on MONO, I got the following Exception:

Exception Object of type 'System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.DuplexServiceRuntimeChannel' doesn't match target type 'System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel'   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00078] in /mcc/mono/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:243 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /mcc/mono/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:114 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientRealProxy.DoInvoke (IMessage inputMessage) [0x0003a] in /mcc/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRealProxy.cs:100 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientRealProxy.Invoke (IMessage inputMessage) [0x00000] in /mcc/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRealProxy.cs:86 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke (System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy rp, IMessage msg, System.Exception& exc, System.Object[]& out_args) [0x0009c] in /mcc/mono/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies/RealProxy.cs:193

has anyone any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Latest GIT!

The Problem is also, when I run the Program 20 times, I can get it to start 1 time without the Exception!